# Linux Docker container not using host localhost

Tags: docker, localhost

Apologies, I know this question is very common but I have now come up against a brick wall and I need a point in the right direction. Thanks.

I am struggling to use a API that is on localhost within a docker container. I have followed many guides but I seem to be missing something. My steps:

In Windows Command prompt, I use the CURL command to fire a GET request to the API on localhost. The request succeeds:

```
curl http://localhost:57888/api/reference

[HttpGet()]
public ActionResult CheckIfOnline()
{
    // Breakpoint hits here
    return Ok();
}
```

Now I would like to call this end-point inside my Docker container. I've tried to do this in the compose file like:

```
container-api:
    container_name: container-api
    build:
        context: ..
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "3007:3001"
    env_file:
        - ./file.env
    extra_hosts:
        - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

I assume from my research this essentially means the container can now 'see' the host machine and, therefore could use localhost? (Happy to be proved wrong)

So when I create the container, I first ping `host.docker.internal` to see if it's available.

```
ping host.docker.internal   
PING host.docker.internal (192.168.65.2) 56(84) bytes of data
```

As you can see, there is a response, but I am not entirely sure what IP 192.168.65.2 is. Looking around the web, it is apparently a 'magic' IP that represents the host IP, I am not sure if this is right as I don't see this IP using 'ipconfig', but for now, I will continue.

> For Docker on Mac, there is a magic ip 192.168.65.2 in docker VM which
> represent host machine, or you can just use host.docker.internal
> inside docker VM will ok.

Lastly I use 'CURL' in the bash container to see if I can hit the API that I hit at the start of this post. However I get this error:

```
# curl http://host.docker.internal:57888/api/reference
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to replace the screen shots with the actual text?  You say "localhost" a couple of times, but there are at least two different localhosts here (on the host system and in the container); where actually is the API?  Are you fundamentally asking [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: Thanks for referencing the guidelines, I shall not upload anymore images and will change this post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Hans led me in the right direction. `host.docker.internal` was indeed connected to my API, but the API didn't like the hostname so it caused the HTTP 400 error.

Therefore in the Docker Compose file, I changed the extra_hosts to this

```
container-api:
    container_name: container-api
    build:
        context: ..
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
        - "3007:3001"
    env_file:
        - ./file.env
    extra_hosts:
        - "localhost:host-gateway"
```

Now the container uses `http://localhost:57888/api/reference` and it connects to the API successfully

Answer (score 1):

With `curl http://host.docker.internal:57888/api/reference` you are indeed connected to your API.

I know that because you get some HTML back. Curl doesn't generate HTML when things go wrong, so the HTML must come from somewhere else: Your API.

Maybe the API doesn't like to be called with a `Host:` header containing `host.docker.internal` and that's why it's returning the 400 error. To figure that out, we'd need more information on how the API is coded and hosted.

Comment: Thank you, this gives me more to go on.  I run the API via IIS Epress in Visual Studio on the host machine i.e. my physical machine, but more importantly, the machine that hosts docker on (vvmem). I will take a punt and say this isn't what you need. Any ideas of where to look in the API to confirm your suspicion? Thanks

Comment: No worries, because of your suggestion, I have solved it. Will put an answer up below. Thanks